# Kusto control commands transaction

Tags: transactions, azure-data-explorer, kql

Is it possible to run Kusto control commands to create/alter multiple Kusto functions in a transaction?  I want to make sure that a set of functions that I create/update all succeed or none at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to execute several such control commands in a transactional way. You can check out [`.execute database script`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/execute-database-script) which allows you to run several control commands in single command (and potentially abort on first failure), but it's not transactional - functions that were updated before failure will *not* be rolled back.